# flash 11.6 shows incorrect text with some colors (like blue, black)

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

In new version of flash players 11.6 sometimes color of text (made with Textfield) not displayed correctly. Example in photo (Color of text should be black on photo).

Comment: Borrowing from some video game forums that I used to read, code (or screen shot in their case) or it didn't happen. Somebody up voted your question, so maybe they are noticing the same problem. But in my opinion, you have to make more of a case than this. At least provide some basic details, like OS, browser, code, and the air speed velocity of an unladen African swallow. Seriously, try to make your case instead of posting two sentences. Again, maybe others are experiencing this, but you don't do very much to convince those who are not :)

Comment: If you cannot embed a screenshot into the question, then just provide a link to there. And yes, a code snippet will be needed too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enable-system-flash-player-google-chrome.html
Solved! In Official Forum of Flash Player.

Comment: +1, that buggy "Pepper Flash" player that is used by Chrome causes a lot of issues. I'm glad you solved the problem... still, I'd like to recommend trying to include more details in your questions (for the future). Cheers!